# Environment variable to Docker container not works

Tags: docker

in /app folder, I have a Google Cloud credential file `ocviam-dev-201b2db30d36.json`

```
> docker exec -ti 9ac6de5f24586320ac41c6e2de9895f03ca87874745257642214852e755a4a99 bash
    root@9ac6de5f2458:/# cd /app/
    root@9ac6de5f2458:/app# ll
    total 252
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr 20 13:42 ./
    drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Apr 20 13:44 ../
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  10875 Apr 20 12:29 function.R*
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    284 Apr 20 09:40 gfs_data_temp12042022.csv*
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 183311 Apr 12 07:33 gfs_data_temp_FULL.csv*
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2331 Mar 22 15:49 ocviam-dev-201b2db30d36.json*
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   3355 Apr 20 12:34 plumber.R*
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  33467 Apr 13 09:39 .RData*
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    405 Apr 13 09:39 .Rhistory*
```

But when I run `docker run -e` option with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable and `/app/ocviam-dev-201b2db30d36.json` value, I get an error:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 80:8000 app1 -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=ocviam-dev-201b2db30d36.json
>>

R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) -- "One Push-Up"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> pr <- plumber::plumb(rev(commandArgs())[1]); args <- list(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8000); if (packageVersion('plumber') >= '1.0.0') { pr$setDocs(TRUE) } else { args$swagger <- TRUE }; do.call(pr$run, args)
Error in plumber::plumb(rev(commandArgs())[1]) :
  File does not exist: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=ocviam-dev-201b2db30d36.json
Execution halted
(base) PS C:\Chantiers\repos\gcp-gfs-weather> docker run --rm -it -p 80:8000 app1 -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/app/ocviam-dev-201b2db30d36.json
>>

R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) -- "One Push-Up"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> pr <- plumber::plumb(rev(commandArgs())[1]); args <- list(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8000); if (packageVersion('plumber') >= '1.0.0') { pr$setDocs(TRUE) } else { args$swagger <- TRUE }; do.call(pr$run, args)
Error in plumber::plumb(rev(commandArgs())[1]) :
  File does not exist: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/app/ocviam-dev-201b2db30d36.json
Execution halted
```

Is it a problem of syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code in question. What language is this plumber thing?

Comment: the error message indicates that the file does not exist *in the container*, whereas you're showing that it exists *on the host*. To mount the folder into the container, try this: `docker run -v ./app:/app -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS...`

Comment: Thanks but I get on Powershell : > docker run --rm -it -p 80:8000 app1 -v ./app:/app -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/app/ocviam-dev-201b2db30d36.json'
WARNING: option '-v' no longer supported

Comment: So how to fix it please?

Comment: Why do you have `*` at the end of your filenames? This could be problematic. In fact, it's not matching your env variable.

Comment: I don't know. This is something I have already observed in the Linux system but without impacts...

Comment: well, as it stands the variable you provide is missing the character, so its simply not matching. However, I would workout why its there and try to get rid of. It could cause problems down the line because a star is also used for pattern matching.

Comment: The `-e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=...` option needs to appear _before_ the image name `app1`.  As you have it _after_ the image name, it's interpreted as the command to run.

Comment: @DavidMaze, the things is looking for the file though, at least thats how the output looks to me. Maybe this app also takes an -e flag. I think its because the filename has a * at the end but the app is not looking for that.

Comment: Although it looks like it wants to use the whole string as filename `File does not exist: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/app/ocviam-dev-201b2db30d36.json`. Maybe the app should be run with `app1 -e /app/ocviam-dev-201b2db30d36.json*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-e` option in **docker run** commands is for passing environment variables as `-e MYVAR1` or `--env MYVAR2=foo`. If you need to pass a file which has the environment variables stored in them, create a file (say "env.list") with contents like this:

> Variable1=Value1
> Variable2=Value2

Post which you can run **docker run --env-file env.list** which will set all the environment variables mentioned in the file.

If your original intention was to authenticate to your Google Cloud Project using the JSON, you should do so using **gcloud auth**:

`gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT] --key-file=KEY_FILE --project=PROJECT_NAME`